# Using Classes within the same named package in Java

Tags: java, class, package

I am trying to create two classes A and B that exist within a named package named components. A is a public class `Window` and B is a public class `Door` which contains an instance of A. The issue is that when compiling B using

```
javac -classpath . Door.java
```

, B cannot find A.

I understand that I can make this code work in an unnamed default package with no import clauses however I want these files to exist within one named class so that they can be imported elsewhere.

I have demonstrated to myself that `Door.java` will compile if the `package components;` line is commented out from both files however I do want to have this as a package named components.

I have also tried using `import components.Window;` within B but this doesn't work either.

```
//class A
package components;
public class Window{
public void rollup(){}
public void rolldown(){}
}

//class B
package components;

public class Door{
    public Window window = new Window();
    public void open(){}
    public void close(){}
}
```

My current code shows this which demonstrates that package B currently cannot access package A.

```
Door.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        Window window = new Window();
        ^
```

How do I fix this code to allow B to create an instance of A whilst being within the same named package?

Comment: Have you compiled `Window.java`?

Comment: You have to execute the command `javac -sourcepath . components/Door.java` in the parent of the folder that contains both classes. For example, if you have Project/components/Door.java, you have to run the command from the folder Project.

Comment: you can't just change the package name you need to move the classes into a directory called components as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking as reference the following structure

```
/some/base/route/project/components
                          |- Window.java
                          |- Door.java
```

Then, running `javac -classpath . components/Door.java` (as well as `javac components/Door.java`) **from `/some/base/route/project`** should work.

Notice that you need to run the command from 1 level *up* the directory that begins conforming the fully qualified package name for the classes. This mean, if you run the command from within `/some/base/route/project/components` it will not work.

Lastly, adding `import components.Window;` in `Door` class is useless because `Window` was already visible in `Door` since both classes are in the same package and `Window` is declared as `public`.

Comment: Yep , perfect. Lesson learnt -  I needed to call javac from a terminal in the directory above this. That's an interesting quirk of java to learn!